# Should you have two periods ending a sentence with et al.?

Tags: punctuation

Let us suppose that I write:

> I read the article from Rossi et al.. Did you?

Is it correct? Should I write two full stops at the end? It sounds very strange to me. "et al." needs a full stop at the end but two in a row...

Should it be like:

> I love cats, women, sunsets etc. What about you?

Comment: When some term has a period and comes at the end of a sentence, there is no need to add another one.

Comment: @Lambie, thanks! Should I delete my question which is maybe obvious for natives?

Comment: Maybe. I never know which rule works. I am not good with rules. :)

Comment: @JKHA please, don't delete it because it still might be of help to English leaners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abbreviations like "etc" and "et al" usually have a period after them. [Style-guides](http://jacklynch.net/Writing/p.html) tend to say that you should not 'double-up' periods - if a sentence ends with "etc", for example, the period is sufficient to abbreviate the word *and* end the sentence, so you would not use two.

By the same rule though, you could combine the period at the end of "etc" with an *ellipsis* - a row of usually 3 periods to indicate either an omitted word in text, or sometimes a deliberate pause in prose, for example:

> I read the article from Rossi et al... did you?

Comment: That is dialogue. Not written English.

Comment: @Lambie I don't understand what you mean - why would we be talking about punctuation marks in dialogue if it wasn't written?